# SQL query for user input

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL query that takes input (customer id via an application) from a user and returns the record but if the id is zero it displays "Invalid ID". The query I have written does show the data correctly when i set an id (SET @CID = ###) but not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Also how can I restrict the user to input a minimum of three digits. Below is the query

```
USE WideWorldImporters
GO

DECLARE @CID int;
SET @CID = @CID

IF @CID > 0
    BEGIN  
SELECT CustomerID, sum(TransactionAmount) as TotalAmount
FROM  Sales.CustomerTransactions  
Where CustomerID = @CID
Group by customerID
        
        RETURN  
    END  
ELSE  

Begin
PRINT 'Invalid ID'  
END;
```

Comment: Your have a `return` statement, which suggests that this is part of a stored procedure or function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff forgot to remove that return but currently I do not have SP for this query

Comment: `SET @CID = @CID`  Im hoping you are actually assigning real value there.  as of now this statement is actually assigning its own value, which doesn't make any sense

Comment: @DeepakSharma  I understand your point but how will it take the user input, if I will assign a specific id then this query will return data for that id only. I'll appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: you want to execute this query in some query runner or in some programming language. to run it directly like in SSMS you can set the value `SET @CID = 99`,or to run from some programming language like C#, Java, etc. better to create PROC and pass Sql parameter to proc.

Comment: @DeepakSharma  Actually I am not sure how these things work because I am not a programming person but what I am trying to do here is to write a code for a stored procedure to interact with .NET application. A user using the application should enter the id at least three digit and get the record for that id but if the value is 0, null or less than  3 digits then it should receive an error message Invalid ID

Comment: ah, then you may need to read little bit about it. may be start with link - https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/07/11/sql-server-pass-parameters-stored-procedure/ it shows how to pass param to proc. similarly you can pass other type or value

Comment: @DeepakSharma thanks a lot, can you suggest if there is anything wrong with the code I wrote, what can I do to take an input in a specific format. Shall I specify the format in the set statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current code. I make the assumption that CustomerID is actually an int. Meaning excess 0 infront of the number are not present. (I.e. 0011 is not an actual ID. Since the column is numeric it will be stored as 11).

With that in mind, you can write the current code into a procedure like such, that will not do a select under the circumstances you described (NULL, minimum of 3 digits and not less than 0).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo
@CID INT
AS
BEGIN
IF (@CID >= 1000) --This works because it's a numeric column. NULL is not greater than 1000 either.
                  --And anything less than 1000 would not be 3 digits.
  BEGIN  
    SELECT CustomerID, SUM(TransactionAmount) as TotalAmount
    FROM  Sales.CustomerTransactions  
    WHERE CustomerID = @CID
    GROUP BY CustomerID
  END  
ELSE
  BEGIN
    --SELECT 'Invalid ID' Use this if you want a single data row to be returned.
                       -- Note this column would be a varchar!
    PRINT 'Invalid ID' -- Print goes to the output window, 
                       -- not the results window like a query would.
  END
END
```

Execution in SQL server would be done as

```
EXEC dbo.foo 1100
```

This because there's only 1 parameter, so you don't have to identity it.
Alternatively the way to call a procedure and explicitly assign parameter values is.

```
EXEC dbo.foo @CID = 1100
```